# WhatsApp Public API

Tags: php, android, api, blackberry, whatsapp

My girlfriend uses Whatsapp on Blackberry. As this is not supported anymore after 2017 I hope to somehow find a way to code an App or a Web App for her, so that she can use her beloved Blackberry.

I found some older Threads about some Whatsapp API's but they seem to have legal problems. Questions:

- Does anyone know a Whatsapp API, that I can use even after the 31. of December 2016

I also though of a second way: Installing Android on a VM in my Datacentre in Paris with a Fixed IP. Configuring Whatsapp on this device and than coding an app, that is something like a Public API on this Device (With authentification of course) and then Coding an App for the Blackberry or a Web App that connects to the API on the Android Device in my Data Centre....

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Whatsapp already has a Web App, isn't that an option? You could run that in a VM for example and read out the text in someway?

Comment: @Sitethief - I think you need to connect it with your phone (start screen asks to scan the QR with your What'sApp-app on your phone).

Comment: Another device is not an option.

I though about Whatsapp Web, but its not working, if you browse this with a phone! Might be a solution to fake the User Agent. 

the VM is not a problem... Is there any way to access the Messages from Whatsapp on this VM if i am on the VM with another app? So I could code this App

Comment: I don't see how you would be able to read or send messages via What'sApp from a third party app, though. Apps are quite sandboxed... and as far as I know, they don't have any public API?

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson True, but you have to authenticate _some way_

Comment: You may use WhatsApi for this. here is the link https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/wiki/WhatsAPI-Documentation .

Also you can find at https://www.phphive.info/285/how-to-send-and-receive-messages-in-whatsapp-using-php/

Answer (score 1):

As a basic recommendation, she might need to get an Android device... if either of you financially can.

On the other hand you might want to look at this API which is an interface to WhatsApp Messenger

https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API

I have yet to use it myself but it has a very neatly Whatsapp integration guide

https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/wiki

**EDIT**:
Also [This](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup) library might help if you know python and want to make an private API for a custom application

Comment: FYI: The Chat-API library is not being supported anymore, unfortunately.

Comment: Links are broken